# Make [hyperledger-composer] the master instead of [fabric-composer]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [fabric-composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-composer) tag was created a few months ago for a new project; since this has been accepted by the Hyperledger Foundation we've had to rebrand.

Sadly, none of the contributors have the sufficient privilege for tag aliasing.

Could I request [hyperledger-composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hyperledger-composer) become the main synonym for [fabric-composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fabric-composer) please?

Comment: I've renamed fabric-composer to hyperledger-composer and fabric-composer is now a synonym of hyperledger-composer. I've also updated the tag excerpt to mention: *Hyperledger Composer (previously Fabric Composer)* - although it wouldn't hurt if someone wanted to suggest/make a more thorough edit (hint hint ;))